# Open a fancybox link with ajax

Tags: jquery, ajax, fancybox, fancybox-2

I use Fancybox on my site to show some content after you click on a link. The code I use for this:

JS in :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('.fancybox').fancybox();
});
```

Link that opens a Fancybox window:

```
<a rel="nofollow" target="_blank" class="fancybox" href="#show_code_8">Show code</a>
```

Code that opens in the Fanctbox window (just an example):

```
<div id="show_code_8" class="inline">
  Some content here
</div>
```

It works correct, but instead of this I want to load the content via ajax. I tried a lot, but can't get it work correctly. I've managed to open the ajax page via ajax, but thats without the right ID (the 8 variable from href="#show_code_8"). Can someone please tell me how I can open the Ajax page with the right ID? How do I pass the variable to the ajax page?

Answer (score 2):

I can think of several possibilities.

One is using a php file that returns the specific code (section) when you call the file with a parameter like

```
<a class="fancybox" href="allCodeContent.php?code=show_code_8" ...
```

Another with jQuery only is using `.load()` to call a specific code (section) from an `.html` file

For example, a file named `allCodeContent.html` may have this content :

```
<div id="show_code_1">This is code one</div>
<div id="show_code_2">This is code two</div>
<div id="show_code_3">This is code three</div>
<div id="show_code_4">This is code four</div>
... etc
```

then, you call each code section in your main page like :

```
<a class="fancybox" href="#show_code_1">show code one in fancybox</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#show_code_2">show code two in fancybox</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#show_code_3">show code three in fancybox</a>
<a class="fancybox" href="#show_code_4">show code four in fancybox</a>
...etc.
```

you may need to create a place holder container (in your main page) to load the code section every time like

```
<div id="ajaxContentPlaceholder" style="display:none;"></div>
```

and then use this script :

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $(".fancybox").on("click", function(){
        var $code = this.href.split("#");
        $("#ajaxContentPlaceholder").load("allCodeContent.html #"+$code[1], function(){
            $.fancybox(this);
        });
        return false;
    }); // on
}); // ready
```

Bear in mind that ajax calls are subject to the [same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy)